# Sending data from flash to php using post method as2

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I am using following code in as3:

```
var Request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var xmlMain:XML=new XML();
var urlXmlLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var myVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

myVars.RequestXml = xmlMain;
Request.url = "http://www.xyz.php"; //some php url

Request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
Request.data = myVars;
urlXmlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlXmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getData);
urlXmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
urlXmlLoader.load(Request);
```

Now I have an as2 project where I need to do the same. How can it be done in as2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the best tutorial on HTTP requests in AS2: http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/loadVars/

Comment: Good example of why link-only answers are of little value. The link is dead.

Comment: I totally agree. Will not make this mistake again. The page can be found in web archive though https://web.archive.org/web/20120920080137/http://sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/loadVars/